# Laravel Relationships Between Table Values

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

This is a rookie question, I know.  But I am building an app for my dissertation where I have three types of users.  I have added a user role to the standard auth system, and set up middleware and routing based on the role.  That all works fine.

But two of my roles are Supervisors (bosses) and DirectReports (employees).  I need to tell the app that one supervisor has many employees, and each employee has one supervisor.  I wouldn't have any issues with this if I had set up Supervisors and Employees as objects, but right now they're just values entered into a table.  Maybe I should have set up a Supervisors table and a Directreports table.  I'm just not sure.  I'm obviously a hobbiest programmer, and trying to do this for a school project.  So I apologize for asking such a basic question.

Comment: I think the best way for your problem is really to create Models for your roles. I know sometimes as a programmer myself, we're too lazy, but sometimes it is the best way to do it and will probably save you a structure change in your app in a near future.

Comment: I'm sure you're right.  Is there a way to create an instance of that model when a user registers--that ties the model to the user?  For my data collection, I need the users to have dashboards based on their roles (supervisors need a different dashboard than direct reports) but the relationship between the models is needed so that on the supervisor dashboard I can loop through their direct reports to create questionnaires about each one.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You should build 2 models, `Supervisors` and `Employees`. With that, if you register a user, you could create a new supervisor instance, set a `user_id` for that instance and save it to the model afterwards. So now, in your Supervisor table you'll have every `user_id` that are Supervisors. Then, in your Employees model, when you create a new Employee, you will set a `user_id` for the employee AND a `supervisor_id` and that's how you are going to retrieve the data eventually with the relationship.

Comment: HUGELY HELPFUL!  Thanks so much!  I will start working toward that end.